# JavaScript - Paste the values from a defined range to the first empty cell in another column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write a macro that would copy the data from range H23:I32 to adjacent columns J23:K60.
Assuming there are values in J23:K60, I wish to paste the data below the last cell with data.

The sheet I am working with is 'Loot'.

Unfortunately, my code doesn't search for the last cell with value and always pastes the data to J23.
Thefore my list gets overwritten instead of values being added to it.

```
function UpdateGroup() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Loot');
const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
sheet.getRange("H23:I23" + lastRow).copyTo(sheet.getRange("J23:K23" + (lastRow + 1)), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

};
```

How do I go about fixing my code so that I have a growing list in J23:K from H23:I values?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

```js
function UpdateGroup() {
  // This is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44563639/7108653
  Object.prototype.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom = function (columnNumber, offsetRow = 1) {
    const search = this.getRange(offsetRow, columnNumber, this.getMaxRows()).createTextFinder(".").useRegularExpression(true).findPrevious();
    return search ? search.getRow() : offsetRow;
  };

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Loot');
  const lastRowH = sheet.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom(8);
  const lastRowJ = sheet.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom(10);
  sheet.getRange("H23:I" + lastRowH).copyTo(sheet.getRange("J" + (lastRowJ+ 1)), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
}
```

- In this modification, the last rows of "H" and "J" are retrieved and use them.
- For example, the last rows of columns "H" and "I" are different and/or the last rows of columns "J" and "K" are different, how about the following modification?

  ```
    function UpdateGroup() {
      // This is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44563639/7108653
      Object.prototype.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom = function (columnNumber, offsetRow = 1) {
        const search = this.getRange(offsetRow, columnNumber, this.getMaxRows()).createTextFinder(".").useRegularExpression(true).findPrevious();
        return search ? search.getRow() : offsetRow;
      };

      const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Loot');
      const lastRowH = sheet.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom(8);
      const lastRowI = sheet.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom(9);
      const lastRowJ = sheet.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom(10);
      const lastRowK = sheet.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom(11);
      sheet.getRange("H23:I" + (lastRowH > lastRowI ? lastRowH : lastRowI))
      .copyTo(sheet.getRange("J" + ((lastRowJ > lastRowK ? lastRowJ : lastRowK) + 1)), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
    }
  ```

### Added:

From your following reply,

> This solved it, thank you!! I did not manage to make the script start checking for last empty cell from J23 and below, but this is not an issue, since I filled J1:J22 with spaces to make these cells 'not blanks'.

In this case, how about the following sample script? In this sample script, when the last rows of the column "J" and "K" are `0`, the value is copied to the row 23.

#### Sample script:

```
function UpdateGroup() {
  // This is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44563639/7108653
  Object.prototype.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom = function (columnNumber, offsetRow = 1) {
    const search = this.getRange(offsetRow, columnNumber, this.getMaxRows()).createTextFinder(".").useRegularExpression(true).findPrevious();
    return search ? search.getRow() : offsetRow;
  };

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Loot');
  const lastRowH = sheet.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom(8);
  const lastRowI = sheet.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom(9);
  const lastRowJ = sheet.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom(10);
  const lastRowK = sheet.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom(11);
  const dest = lastRowJ > lastRowK ? lastRowJ : lastRowK;
  sheet.getRange("H23:I" + (lastRowH > lastRowI ? lastRowH : lastRowI))
  .copyTo(sheet.getRange("J" + ((dest >= 22 ? dest : 22) + 1)), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into this!!

The last row is always the same for J and K, however the modification below does not do anything when I run the script - could it be because for the first run my J:K are empty? 



sheet.getRange("H23:I23" + lastRow).copyTo(sheet.getRange("J" + (lastRow + 1)), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

Comment: @Xiggie Thank you for replying. If my proposed modification was not the direct solution and I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: The second option does work - but I am getting weird placement in J column: 
If I leave the code as is - 
sheet.getRange("H23:I23" + lastRow).copyTo(sheet.getRange("J" + (lastRow + 1)), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
The values start getting added from J2 .

If I attempt to specify that the values should be check J23 and below -
sheet.getRange("H23:I23" + lastRow).copyTo(sheet.getRange("J23" + (lastRow + 1)), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
Then the values start getting added from J232.

This is most peculiar!

Comment: @Xiggie Thank you for replying. I have to apologize. I noticed that I misunderstood your situation. So I modified my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: This solved it, thank you!! 

I did not manage to make the script start checking for last empty cell from J23 and below, but this is not an issue, since I filled J1:J22 with spaces to make these cells 'not blanks'.

Comment: @Xiggie Thank you for replying. From your reply, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? In the additional script, when the last rows of the column "J" and "K" are `0`, the value is copied to the row 23.

Comment: This one works wonders, it is beautiful!! I would upvote you but I lack rep to do it. I would have never been able to come up with an elegant script like this, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

#### A Bit more of a mechanical approach

GS:

```
function srcToDst() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("ah2").setWidth(350).setHeight(150),"SRC-DST");
}

function getSRCRg() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg = sh.getActiveRange();
  return {SRC: `'${sh.getName()}'!${rg.getA1Notation()}`};
}

function getDSTRg() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg = sh.getActiveRange();
  return {DST: `'${sh.getName()}'!${rg.getA1Notation()}`};
}

function copySRCDSTs(obj) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getRange(obj.SRC).copyTo(ss.getRange(obj.DST));
}

function moveSRCDSTs(obj) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getRange(obj.SRC).moveTo(ss.getRange(obj.DST));
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function getSRC() {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#ffff00";
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(obj => {
        document.getElementById("src").value = obj.SRC;
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
      })
      .getSRCRg();
    }
    function getDST() {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#ffff00";
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(obj => {
        document.getElementById("dst").value = obj.DST;
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
      })
      .getDSTRg();
    }
    function moveSRCDST() {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#ffff00";
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(obj => {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
      })
      .moveSRCDSTs({SRC: $('#src').val(),DST: $('#dst').val()})
    }
    function copySRCDST() {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#ffff00";
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(obj => {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
      })
      .copySRCDSTs({SRC: $('#src').val(),DST: $('#dst').val()})
    }
    console.log("Move SRC to DST")
  </script>
  <style>
    input{margin:2px 5px 2px 0;}
    #container{width:100%;}
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
   <form>
      <input type="text" size="25" id="src" placeholder="Select Source Range Press SRC" />
      <input type="button" value="SRC" onClick="getSRC();" />
      <br /><input type="text" size="25" id="dst" placeholder="Select Dest Range Press DST" />
      <input type="button" value="DST" onClick="getDST();" />
      <br /><input type="Button" value="Move" onClick="moveSRCDST();" /> 
      <input type="Button" value="Copy" onClick="copySRCDST();" />
    </form>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is a wonderful approach as well, however I needed to have my script executed with a single button with a predefined range since it is built into a sheet with multiple dependencies and multiple 'before' and 'after' scripts. A great source of information none the less!